# Why does my template code not appear on my Flask page on http://127.0.0.1:5000/?

Tags: python, flask

When I run my app.py code without any templates, everthing goes smoothly, but when I run my app.py code, connected with a template, I see an empty flask page infront of me on my computer. I have installed a virtual environment in my project. My template .html file is connected to the 'templates' folder and have my app.py folder separately connected to my project folder.

app.py:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/home')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is a test template</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the URL you try in your browser

Comment: Your Python code contains `@app.route('/home')`, but the title of your question here mentions that you tried to open http://127.0.0.1:5000/. Just to be sure: does the problem also appear when you go to http://127.0.0.1:5000/home in your browser? And does VSCode display any errors or warnings anywhere about the files not being found?

Comment: Even though I try the url 127.0.0.1:5000/home in my home browser, I still don't see my template text. The VSCode terminal does not display any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You said that your index.html is in a folder called templates and your app.py in a folder separately. If the templates folder is in a different folder from the one app.py lives in then it won't be able to find the templates folder. You could either make sure templates is in the same folder as app.py or you can set the app's template folder like `app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='C:\\path\to\your\templates\folder')`